# Calendar + Custom Google Script - if title includes a number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to setup a Custom Google Script to automatically color code my calendar based on keywords in the title. I have everything working properly, *except* for any events that start with a number.

Here's my script in question:

```
   if (title.includes("1:1")) {
    e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.YELLOW);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Find titles that begin with a number

`title.match(/^\d+/);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `onEdit()`

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var selectedColumn = cellRange.getColumn();
  var selectedRow = cellRange.getRow();

  sheet.getRange(selectedColumn,selectedRow).setBackground("red");
  sheet.getRange(selectedColumn,selectedRow).setFontColor('white');
```